# How to multuply current data base row value in one Update sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have DB table and want divide/multiply row record , how it is possible to do it with one SQL Update query, hope your ideas will help to resolve the problem  thanks. 
I have tried the following query but failed

```
query.exec("UPDATE "+people+ " WHERE id = "+id + " SET ticket_price = ticket_price*2")
```

Comment: Try this way:`query.exec("UPDATE "+people+ " SET ticket_price = ticket_price*2" +" WHERE id = "+id)`

Comment: Harshil, thanks it helped

Comment: Sql Injection warning https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `where` clause comes after the `set` clause, not before it:

```
UPDATE people
SET    ticket_price = ticket_price * 2
WHERE  id = <some id>
```